# Численное решение задачи теплопроводности

Tags: python, численные-методы

Необходимо решить задачу теплопроводности на отрезке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При решении использовала явную схему

```
N = 10 # максимальное число шагов по х
K = 10 # максимальное число шагов по t
l = 1 # значение х на правой границе
h = l / N # шаг сетки по х
T = 1 # максимальное значение времени t на правой границе
t = T / K # шаг сетки по времени

# зададим сетку 
x_i = np.arange(0, N, h) # значения в узлах по х
t_j = np.arange(0, K, t) # значение в узлах по t
r_j = len(t_j) # количество узлов по t
r_i = len(x_i) # количество узлов по x
w_h_t = np.zeros([r_i, r_j]) # итоговая сетка размером x_i*t_j

# зададим значение функции входящей в начальное уравнение
x = 0
def f(x):
    return np.sin(x)

# граничные условия
ux_0 = 1 # граничное условие на левом конце при x=0
ut_0 = np.cos(x_i) # граничное условие при t=0

# найдем значения на нулевом слое при t=0 ut_0 = np.cos(x_i)
w_h_t[0] = np.cos(x_i)

# найдем значения w_h_t на первом и последующих слоях
const = t / (h**2) 
for j in range(1, len(x_i)-1):
    for i in range(len(w_h_t[j])-1):        
        w_h_t[j+1, i] = w_h_t[j, i] + const * (w_h_t[j,i] - 2*w_h_t[j,i] + w_h_t[j, i-1]) + t*f(x_i[j])
        w_h_t[j+1, 0] = 1
        w_h_t[j+1, len(w_h_t[i])-1] = w_h_t[j+1, len(w_h_t[i])-2] + h * t_j[j+1]


plot_ = np.arange(0,len(w_h_t)-1,1)
for y in plot_:
    plt.plot(x_i, w_h_t[y])
```

В результате получила вот такой график зависимости Х от рассчитанного значения функции в узлах сетки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне не понятно насколько неверно мое решение. Возникли проблемы с поиском частного решения, wolfram выдал `u(x) = 1.54x+1+sinx`, что мне кажется не верным, а самой решить не получилось. В учебнике Филиппова похожих примеров не нашлось, в сети ничего достаточно подробного, чтобы разобраться в решении не нашла. Подскажите где можно найти как решать аналитически такое уравнение и насколько неверно мое решение? В чем ошибка? И как вообще проверяют на корректность решения таких задач, кроме как сравнения с аналитическим решением?

---

В общем и целом разобралась. Решила дополнить свой вопрос отредактированным решением, возможно, кому-то пригодится.
Численное решение правильно найти так и не удалось, но находится оно методом Фурье(разделение переменных). 
Итоговый график:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рабочий код:

```
N = 10 # максимальное число шагов по х
K = 500 # максимальное число шагов по t
l = 1 # значение х на правой границе
h = l / N # шаг сетки по х
T = 1 # максимальное значение времени t на правой границе
t = T / K # шаг сетки по времени


# зададим сетку 
x_i = np.arange(0, 1, h) # значения в узлах по х
t_j = np.arange(0, 1, t) # значение в узлах по t
r_j = len(t_j) # количество узлов по t
r_i = len(x_i) # количество узлов по x
w_h_t = np.zeros([r_j, r_i]) # итоговая сетка размером x_i*t_j


# зададим значение функции входящей в начальное уравнение
x = 0
def f(x):
    return np.sin(x)

# граничные условия
ux_0 = 1 # граничное условие на левом конце при x=0
ut_0 = np.cos(x_i) # граничное условие при t=0

# найдем значения на нулевом слое при t=0 ut_0 = np.cos(x_i)
w_h_t[0] = np.cos(x_i)

# найдем значения w_h_t на первом и последующих слоях
const = t / (h**2) 
for j in range(len(w_h_t) - 1):
    for i in range(len(w_h_t[j]) - 1):        
        w_h_t[j + 1, i] = w_h_t[j, i] + const* (w_h_t[j, i+1] - 2 * w_h_t[j, i] + w_h_t[j, i - 1]) + t*f(x_i[i])
        w_h_t[j + 1, 0] = 1
        w_h_t[j + 1, len(w_h_t[i])-1] = w_h_t[j + 1, len(w_h_t[i])-1] + h
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

К сожалению не специалист именно в теплопроводности, но могу отметить несколько точно проблемных моментов:

1. В настоящий момент шаг по сетке времени не связан с шагом по сетке в пространстве. В явных схемах - это ведет к нестабильности. Нужно соблюдать [критерий CFL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9A%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8). В вашем случае, если я правильно помню термодинамику, `Δt < CFL * χ * (Δx)²`. То есть `Δt < (Δx)²` (χ - radiative diffusion в вашем уравнении = 1). В вашей программе это явно не соблюдается ни по конкретным значениям, ни по алгоритму. Решение: привяжите `K` и `N` друг к другу.
2. По вашему графику очень сложно понять что происходит. Если начертить каждый шаг времени на отдельном графике - то видно, что численное решение расходится. В частности, это видно и на вашем чертеже (`e121`). Объясняется как минимум пунктом 1, и, возможно, еще какими-то проблемами в программе. Кроме того, решения на промежуточных шагах выглядят ну очень подозрительно.
3. Посмотрите значения `x_i` и `t_j` (`print(x_i)`) - сейчас это массивы от `0` до `9.9`  с шагом `0.1`. Судя по условию, перепутан шаг, количество шагов и правая граница.

Теперь по проверке решений. Формально, такой код можно проверить через [Method of Manufactured Solutions](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/759450), но для вашего задания это, конечно, слишком.

При обучении численным методам чаще всего используются задачи для которых известно аналитическое решение и полученный результат сравнивается уже с ним. Еще стоит проверять:

- выполняются ли начальные и конечные условия
- анализ сходимости (убавили шаг по времени - стало лучше? убавили шаг дискретизации в пространстве - стало лучше?)
- не появляется ли энергия из ниоткуда (для замкнутых систем)?
- совпадает ли решение с решением из коммерческого\open-source симулятора?
- если решить уравнение другим численным методом (например, методом конечных элементов), получим ли мы примерно тоже самое?

Comment: Не могу разобраться, что именно перепутано в пункте 3? Можно поподробнее? У меня действительно не соблюден критерий устойчивости явной схемы  t/h^2<1/2. Это исправлю. Спасибо!

Comment: @jokop выведите значения массивов `x_i` и `t_j`. Они будут от 0 до 9.9. Это противоречит условию, если я правильно понимаю. Вроде как они должны быть от 0 до 1  c определенным шагом.

Comment: Изменила K, теперь K = 25 и x_i = np.arange(0, 1, h) t_j = np.arange(0, 1, t) теперь график выглядит так:  https://ibb.co/Qmgp555

Comment: все равно нестабильно. K=25 - маловато при N=10. Минимум K=100 (смотрите CFL), а лучше чуть больше.

Comment: Да, вы правы, но если взять K=250, то получается вот такой график https://ibb.co/T4ryf4j, что кажется странным, хотя условия на границе выполняются, так что может и правда

Comment: @jokop ну как минимум- он не взорвался до `e121`. Значит кое-какие проблемы мы уже победили :) Остальное - нужно смотреть более внимательно, с обновленным кодом и, возможно, референсным решением.

Comment: Дополнила вопрос по моему мнению правильным решением. Хотелось бы, по возможности,  услышать комментарии экспертов относительно правильности решения.